# Passing a function with the same name gets "ambiguous" error

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to pass a function using the following typealias to define it:

```
 typealias AuthFunction = (String, String, AuthDataResultCallback?) -> ()
```

this is then used in the following function:

```
    private func checkAuth(authFunc: AuthFunction) {
        if emailTextField.text == "" {
            showAlert(title: String.Localized.Common.error,
                      message: String.Localized.Common.enterEmailAndPassword)
        } else {
            guard let email = emailTextField.text,
                    let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }

            authFunc(email, password) { [weak self] (user, error) in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                strongSelf.checkAfterAuth(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have done this so I can call some Firebase auth functions that do the different things but have the same result. I also wanted to see if I could refactor this way as I've never tried it before.

It works fine when calling like so:

```
checkAuth(authFunc: Auth.auth().createUser)
```

The problem im running into is that the firebase SDK has a couple functions that begin with `signIn`:

```
signIn(withEmail: , password:, completion:)
signIn(with:, completion:)
signIn(withEmail:, link:, completion:)
```

This means when calling `checkAuth(authFunc: Auth.auth().signIn)` i get `Ambiguous use of 'signIn'` because `signIn` has multiple definitions.

Is there anyway around this?

Update:

Firebase definitions on both the calls:

```
- (void)createUserWithEmail:(NSString *)email
               password:(NSString *)password
             completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;

- (void)signInWithEmail:(NSString *)email
           password:(NSString *)password
         completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
```

Comment: completion block has different signature in firebase.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh i dont think your right, see my updates

Comment: Sign in signatures ?

Comment: `signIn` is `signInWithEmail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
checkAuth(authFunc: Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail:password:completion:))

checkAuth(authFunc: Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail:link:completion:))
```

(You may have found similar notations inside `#selector()`.)